# GitConfig: bad config for shell command

Tags: git, git-config, git-alias

I'm trying to set up an alias, as I have many.

For some reason, this one does not work. Any idea?

```
[alias]
t = "!git log --decorate --oneline | egrep '^[0-9a-f]+ \(tag: ' | sed -r 's/^.+tag: ([^ ]+)[,\)].+$/\1/g'"
```

Command works fine by itself:

```
$ git log --decorate --oneline | egrep '^[0-9a-f]+ \(tag: ' | sed -r 's/^.+tag: ([^ ]+)[,\)].+$/\1/g'
1.0.0
0.9.0
...
$ git t
fatal: bad config file line 28 in /Users/alanschneider/.gitconfig
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backslash ("`\`") characters are read by git itself in your config. Just escape them again with a second backslash and it will work:

```
t = "!git log --decorate --oneline | egrep '^[0-9a-f]+ \\(tag: ' | sed -r 's/^.+tag: ([^ ]+)[,\\)].+$/\\1/g'"
```

Comment: Snap that was it. I did but forgot `\\(` before `tag`. Thanks