# How to git grep the main repository and all its submodules?

Tags: git, grep, git-submodules

I found this at a blog to grep project and submodules:

```
[alias]
  sgrep = "!f() { git grep \"$1\"; git submodule foreach \"git grep '$1'; true\" | grep -B 1 \"$1\"; }; f"
```

I updated my `~/.gitconfig` to include it, but when I use the alias, it says:

`fatal: bad config file line 9 in /home/myname/.gitconfig`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, similar to "[GitConfig: bad config for shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13583083/6309)", it may be because the '`\`' character is interpreted by git first, before being executed in a shell.

But in your case, this should work as expected because of the surrounding double-quotes.
It does work on my git 1.8.4 on Ubuntu.

So simplify your `.gitconfig` and check if works better if it contains your alias (and *nothing*) else.
If that does work, then the issue is elsewhere in your config file.

Answer (score 31):

With Git 2.12 (Q1 2017), you won't need any `git submodule foreach` trick.
Simply:

```
 git grep -e "bar" --recurse-submodules
```

See [commit e6fac7f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6fac7f3d3e313a93fe9b1243917669267b33153), [commit 74ed437](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74ed43711fd1cd7ce155d338f87ebe52cb74d9e2), [commit 0281e48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0281e487fd913bd9a32a710f3109ff3002f3e4a9), [commit 4538eef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4538eef564c81c96f2874ccadc54d3c69cc0e19c), [commit 9ebf689](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ebf689aad72bfc091da21e1d73a05308f1ace85), [commit f9f4256](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9f42560e2911a5eef9a3d463a63cfd48d54dd07), [commit 5688c28](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5688c28d81e9103a234efeedcb0568c2c4dd0bfb) (16 Dec 2016), and [commit 4ac9006](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ac9006f832d98ca1f25d956e12f3ff79e0d25bc), [commit 7241764](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72417640769c91408d15cdbab3160bc494f49c7f), [commit a1ae484](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1ae48410dce23c1e81e76aabaeb4eb01b065763), [commit 05b458c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05b458c104708141d2fad211d79703b3b99cc5a8) (12 Dec 2016) by [Brandon Williams (`mbrandonw`)](https://github.com/mbrandonw).
See [commit e9a379c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9a379c352b02ca560c58a56aa723994aa42666f) (21 Dec 2016) by [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 55d128a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55d128ae06b7b82f867961b677984620612a201c), 18 Jan 2017)</sup>

> ### `grep`: optionally recurse into submodules
>
> Allow `grep` to recognize submodules and recursively search for patterns in
>   each submodule.
>   This is done by forking off a process to recursively call grep on each submodule.
>
> Recursion only occurs for submodules which have been initialized and
>   checked out by the parent project. If a submodule hasn't been initialized and checked out it is simply skipped.
>
> In order to support the existing multi-threading infrastructure in `grep`,
>   output from each child process is captured in a strbuf so that it can be later printed to the console in an ordered fashion.
>
> To limit the number of theads that are created, each child process has
>   half the number of threads as its parents (minimum of 1), otherwise we
>   potentially have a fork-bomb.

The [`git grep` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/55d128ae06b7b82f867961b677984620612a201c/Documentation/git-grep.txt#L92-L96) now includes:

```
--recurse-submodules
```

> Recursively search in each submodule that has been initialized and
>    checked out in the repository.
>   When used in combination with the `<tree>` option the prefix of all submodule output will be the name of the parent project's `<tree>` object.

---

With Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2017), "`git grep --recurse-submodules`" has been reworked to give a more consistent output across submodule boundary (and do its thing without having to fork a separate process).

See [commit f9ee2fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9ee2fcdfa05586b6a4476c7aa5f4f0162e48455), [commit 2184d4b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2184d4ba0cb86a7f40153cd46b03d3fa75b247d9), [commit 34e2ba0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34e2ba04be4f8e11d91b2508aa8ca84148fe63f1), [commit 91b8348](https://github.com/git/git/commit/91b834807b98b620050fe534b6de93e223dbcbcf), [commit 8fa2915](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8fa2915971e5032e6a32f5096452db81ab8795eb), [commit f20e7c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f20e7c1ea2459d9b8c12f8ed1f1546665841b643), [commit b22e51c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b22e51cb26bc93bd1548950e61970a9973e04b70), [commit 4c0eeaf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c0eeafe4755345b0f4636bf09904cf689703e11) (02 Aug 2017), and [commit ba43964](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ba43964d47ac29eafafd8d475c299c51c8a1ca75), [commit 3f13877](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f13877595500bd54ee370167bc868f3c1eee5b7) (18 Jul 2017) by [Brandon Williams (`mbrandonw`)](https://github.com/mbrandonw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5aa0b6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5aa0b6c506c1f1336d0e713bf8225509e9ebb9f5), 22 Aug 2017)</sup>

That means the internal [`--parent-basename <basename>`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9ee2fcdfa05586b6a4476c7aa5f4f0162e48455) option of `git grep` does no longer exists.

---

Make sure to use Git 2.21 (Q1 2019), as a bug has been fixed regarding cywin paths: see "[Cygwin uses relative and absolute path for environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298834/6309)".

---

Actually, *before* Git 2.23.1/2.24 (Q4 2019), "`git grep --recurse-submodules`" that looks at the working tree files looked at the contents in the index in submodules, **instead of files in the working tree**.

That has been fixed.

See [commit 6a289d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a289d45c0e5d155f536d7c1f73c3b33690e92c6) (30 Jul 2019) by [Matheus Tavares (`matheustavares`)](https://github.com/matheustavares).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3071797](https://github.com/git/git/commit/307179732d580735c579b9bfae2eaf7a536f4ae9), 22 Aug 2019)</sup>

> ### `grep`: fix worktree case in submodules
>
> Running `git-grep` with `--recurse-submodules` results in a cached `grep` for
>   the submodules even when `--cached` is not used.
>   This makes all modifications in submodules' tracked files be always ignored when
>   grepping.
>
> Solve that making `git grep` respect the cached option when invoking `grep_cache()` inside [`grep_submodule()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a289d45c0e5d155f536d7c1f73c3b33690e92c6/builtin/grep.c#L403-L406).
>   Also, add tests to ensure that the desired behavior is performed.

---

"`git grep --no-index`" should not get affected by the contents of the `.gitmodules` file but when "`--recurse-submodules`" is given or the "`submodule.recurse`" variable is set, it did.

No more, with Git 2.25.1 (Feb. 2020).
Now these settings are ignored in the "`--no-index`" mode.

See [commit c56c48d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c56c48dd0750dc7759f5e9a33cd4a01d6162b06e) (30 Jan 2020) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 556ccd4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/556ccd4dd2943009270b46b9af443a396bff4dfc), 12 Feb 2020)</sup>
[See discussion](https://public-inbox.org/git/pull.540.git.1580000298097.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/T/#u).

> ### [`grep`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c56c48dd0750dc7759f5e9a33cd4a01d6162b06e): ignore `--recurse-submodules` if `--no-index` is given
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>
>
> Since grep learned to recurse into submodules in [0281e487fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0281e487fd913bd9a32a710f3109ff3002f3e4a9) ("`grep`: optionally recurse into submodules", 2016-12-16, Git v2.12.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55d128ae06b7b82f867961b677984620612a201c) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/787f75f0567aa8c7347544c65e9d3bc6640a27d4)), **using `--recurse-submodules` along with `--no-index` makes Git `die()`**.
>
> This is unfortunate because if `submodule.recurse` is set in a user's `~/.gitconfig`, invoking `git grep --no-index` either inside or outside a Git repository results in:
>
> ```
> fatal: option not supported with --recurse-submodules
> ```
>
> Let's allow using these options together, so that setting submodule.recurse globally does not prevent using `git grep --no-index`.
>
> Using `--recurse-submodules` should not have any effect if `--no-index` is used inside a repository, as Git will recurse into the checked out submodule directories just like into regular directories.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298834/6309, since a regression for cygwin users was introduced with commit 05b458c, "real_path: resolve symlinks by hand", Dec. 2016, Git v2.12.0-rc0.