# Cygwin uses relative and absolute path for environment variables

Tags: git, go, cygwin

When I use the below command in Cygwin:

```
$ go get github.com/gorilla/mux
```

I receive the below error:

```
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/gorilla/mux C:\cygwin64\home\USER\Go\src\github.com\gorilla\mux
Cloning into 'C:\cygwin64\home\USER\Go\src\github.com\gorilla\mux'...
fatal: Invalid path '/home/USER/C:\cygwin64\home\USER\Go\src\github.com\gorilla\mux': No such file or directory
package github.com/gorilla/mux: exit status 128
```

When I use the command:

```
cd $GOPATH
```

The correct folder opens.

Does anyone how I can solve this?

Comment: `go` is not a cygwin program, so no surprise it does not understand POSIX path. Have you tried to run it from `CMD` ?

Comment: And you will need a windows or msys/mingw32 version of `git`. The cygwin and the windows versions of `git` can be made compatible using `git config` but you will still have problems with paths.

Answer (score 1):

Try the same command with Git 2.21 (Q1 2019) installed.

See [commit 1cadad6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1cadad6f658bfb3ab54b25dd04bac372253473b6) (15 Dec 2018) by [Torsten Bögershausen (`tboegi`)](https://github.com/tboegi).
Helped-by: [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 25d90d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25d90d1cb72ce51407324259516843406142fe89), 14 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### `git clone <url> C:\cygwin\home\USER\repo` is working (again)
>
> A regression for cygwin users was introduced with [commit 05b458c, Git v2.12.0-rc0, Dec. 2012](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05b458c104708141d2fad211d79703b3b99cc5a8), "`real_path`: resolve symlinks by hand".

(See "[How to `git grep` the main repository and all its submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41788645/6309)" for more on that original commit)

> In the the commit message we read:
>
> > The current implementation of real_path uses `chdir()` in order to resolve symlinks.  Unfortunately this isn't thread-safe as `chdir()` affects a process as a whole...
>
> The old (and non-thread-save) OS calls `chdir()`/`pwd()` had been replaced by a string operation.
>   The cygwin layer "knows" that "`C:\cygwin`" is an absolute path, but the new string operation does not.
>
> ```
> "git clone <url> C:\cygwin\home\USER\repo" fails like this:
> fatal: Invalid path '/home/USER/repo/C:\cygwin\home\USER\repo'
> ```

(which is an error message similar to what the OP mentions)

> The solution is to implement `has_dos_drive_prefix()`, `skip_dos_drive_prefix()` `is_dir_sep()`, `offset_1st_component()` and `convert_slashes()` for cygwin
>   in the same way as it is done in 'Git for Windows' in `compat/mingw.[ch]`.
>
> Extract the needed code into `compat/win32/path-utils.[ch]` and use it for cygwin as well.

---

Note: Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) further improves the command, as an earlier update for MinGW and Cygwin accidentally broke MSVC build, which has been fixed.

See [commit 22c3634](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22c3634c0f92662f995e1e97db7f65bb39352080) (08 Apr 2019) by [Sven Strickroth (`apotek`)](https://github.com/apotek).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 70542df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70542df56618f2766064384f7741c7e25bac1cfd), 08 May 2019)</sup>

> ### MSVC: include compat/win32/path-utils.h for MSVC, too, for real_path()
>
> A path such as '`c:/somepath/submodule/../.git/modules/submodule`' wasn't
>   resolved correctly any more, because the *nix variant of `offset_1st_component` is used instead of the Win32 specific version.
>
> Regression was introduced in [commit 1cadad6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1cadad6f658bfb3ab54b25dd04bac372253473b6) when `mingw_offset_1st_component` was moved from `mingw.c`, which is included by `msvc.c` to a separate file.
>   Then, the new file "`compat/win32/path-utils.h`" was only included for the `__CYGWIN__` and `__MINGW32__` cases in `git-compat-util.h`, the case for `_MSC_VER` was missing.

And:

> ### `git clone <url> C:\cygwin\home\USER\repo` is working (again)
>
> A regression for cygwin users was introduced with [commit 05b458c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05b458c104708141d2fad211d79703b3b99cc5a8), "real_path: resolve symlinks by hand", Dec. 2016, Git v2.12.0-rc0.
>
> In the the commit message we read:
>
> > The current implementation of real_path uses chdir() in order to resolve symlinks.
> >     Unfortunately this isn't thread-safe as chdir() affects a process as a whole...
>
> The old (and non-thread-save) OS calls `chdir()`/`pwd()` had been
>   replaced by a string operation.
>   The cygwin layer "knows" that "`C:\cygwin`" is an absolute path,
>   but the new string operation does not.
>
> "`git clone <url> C:\cygwin\home\USER\repo`" fails like this:
>
> ```
> fatal: Invalid path '/home/USER/repo/C:\cygwin\home\USER\repo'
> ```
>
> The solution is to implement `has_dos_drive_prefix()`, `skip_dos_drive_prefix()` `is_dir_sep()`, `offset_1st_component()` and `convert_slashes()` for cygwin
>   in the same way as it is done in 'Git for Windows' in `compat/mingw.[ch]`
>
> Extract the needed code into `compat/win32/path-utils.[ch]` and use it
>   for cygwin as well.

---

Note: The `real_path()` convenience function can easily be misused; with a bit of code refactoring in the callers' side, its use has been eliminated, with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020).

See [commit 49d3c4b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49d3c4b481f12c2ec655a71d5a5b9259a398d059), [commit 4530a85](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4530a85b4c34f009b5f190eb2dc8367801de5028), [commit 3d7747e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d7747e318532a36a263c61cdf92f2decb6424ff) (10 Mar 2020), and [commit 0915a5b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0915a5b4cdf00a8c6c755b77b854725a183993b4) (06 Mar 2020) by [Alexandr Miloslavskiy (`SyntevoAlex`)](https://github.com/SyntevoAlex).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4d0e899](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d0e8996ec54e53149c2f24075eb64921ca61812), 25 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`real_path`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d7747e318532a36a263c61cdf92f2decb6424ff): remove unsafe API
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alexandr Miloslavskiy</sup>
>
> Returning a shared buffer invites very subtle bugs due to reentrancy or multi-threading, as demonstrated by the previous patch.
>
> There was an [unfinished effort to abolish this](https://lore.kernel.org/git/1480964316-99305-1-git-send-email-bmwill@google.com/).
>
> Let's finally rid of `real_path()`, using `strbuf_realpath()` instead.
>
> This patch uses a local `strbuf` for most places where `real_path()` was previously called.
>
> However, two places return the value of `real_path()` to the caller. For them, a `static` local `strbuf` was added, effectively pushing the problem one level higher:
>
> ```
> read_gitfile_gently()
> get_superproject_working_tree()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think this comes if you have git both installed locally and in cygwin. For me it helped running the `go get` command in the git cmd

Comment: can you please amplify what you mean by "in the git cmd"?  thanks, the above doesn't fix the problem for me.

Comment: I'm guessing they mean using this program, https://gitforwindows.org/ Which comes with its own shell.

Answer (score 0):

Although by using Windows' git-bash.exe is a work around, yet some might find it fundamental to stay in their cygwin environment. To make it work in cygwin, do this:

Instead of:

```
go get -u -v github.com/golang/example/hello
```

You need to instead do it by:

```
git clone https://github.com/golang/example $(cygpath -u $GOPATH)/src/github.com/golang/example
```